# ExpressionEngine add javascript to CP head

Tags: control-panel, javascript, extension

I have been struggling with this for a while now and am stuck I am writing an extension for ExpressionEngine 2 (not a module) and need to add a script tag to the header of the page.

I have tried:

```
$script = "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('added');</script>";
$this->EE->cp->add_to_head($script);
```

but im guessing this only works when its a module, i have also tried (which i am pretty sure should work):

```
$this->EE->cp->load_package_js('file');
```

but i get the following error:

```
Call to a member function plugin() on a non-object in expressionengine/libraries/Cp.php on line 766
```

I have also tried using the hook `cp_js_end` which loads the file but its loaded after everything else thus it does not work as intended.

Any Ideas?

**EDIT**

After playign around with this it looks as if you can only use `$this->EE->cp->load_package_js('file');` for modules and not extensions.

I will close this issue

Answer (score 7):

Loading assets within an add-on can be tricky if you don't know how to do it properly. For instance, your code is likely failing because it's relying the CP (control panel) to serve the assets. So, if the CP class is not instantiated, your code will fail.

I suggest you take a look at Theme Loader, my open source library I use for all my add-ons. It works very well, and it will automatically make your script with RequireJS too (an added bonus of using the Theme Loader abstraction). The best part about Theme Loader, is it makes it also compatible with the Master Config boostrap, and supports changing the default place to store the add-ons. For instance, if you move your stuff above webroot, Theme Loader automatically takes care of it.

https://github.com/objectivehtml/Theme-Loader

Make sure you do the following:

1. Make sure your add-on has a directory inside of "themes/third_party". Without this, your assets will fail to be served properly.
2. Make sure your add-on asset directly structure is correct, which should be at a minimum:

   - themes/third_party/your_addon
   - themes/third_party/your_addon/css
   - themes/third_party/your_addon/javascript

(Obviously if you don't need JS, don't include that directory. But this is the default structure Theme Loaders expects, so follow it and you will be good.)

Example Code

```
$this->EE->load->library('theme_loader');
$this->EE->theme_loader->module_name = 'your_module'; // Note, your addon doesn't have to be a real "module".

$this->EE->theme_loader->css('styles');
$this->EE->theme_loader->js('app');
$this->EE->theme_loader->output('alert("do something");');
```

Comment: that looks good, will have to try but it doesn't answer the question. I am pretty sure `$this->EE->cp->load_package_js('file');` should work but not sure why i get the errors.

Comment: @4razmus based on the code in your comment do you have a JavaScript file called file.js in the javascript folder? http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/development/usage/cp.html#loading-javascript-files

Comment: yep. Its all correct. Works flawlessly with a module just not extensions..

Comment: Is the extension being called outside the control panel? I said, "...your code is likely failing because it's relying the CP (control panel) to serve the assets...". There is a class called cp, it's only instantiated when the control panel is loaded. If it's not instantiated, your code will fail. It's possible Theme Load will too after thinking about it. What hooks are you using for your extension?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that you cant load javascript in an extension as you would a module. The above worked fine in a module but errors are produced.

After speaking with a colleague it may be possible to do this with an Accessory hack.

Comment: That a look at how RequireJS for EE adds JS to the page. It's a really clever way to do it and not rely on any of the classes. https://github.com/ckimrie/RequireJS-for-EE

Comment: yeah i see what they are doing - just doing a string replace on the final output. decided to write a module anyway, but thanks